# Find a particular nesting of directory names, e.g. .../project/dir1/dir2

Tags: shell-script, find, directory

I'm having some issues dealing with the `find` command; I don't know the syntax for it very well and I need to use it in a script to find a specific directory structure that could be located anywhere.

Basically, I have a structure like "project/dir1/dir2" that I know will always be exactly those three directories, with the same names, in that order.  What may not be the same is how deep this structure is nested; for example you could have:

`$HOME/project/dir1/dir2`

or

`$HOME/workspace/project/dir1/dir2`

Basically I need a general way to locate the `project/dir1/dir2` structure no matter how far deeply buried it is.

This will always be on Ubuntu.  I thought about using locate, but then I'd have to guarantee that the locate db is always up to date.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you used `find -name project/dir1/dir2` you will find a message like this:

> find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that `-name 'project/dir1/dir2'` will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the `-wholename` test more useful, or perhaps `-samefile`.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use `find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ`project/dir1/dir2'`.

So, it offers certain alternatives for such task. Weird it doesn't mention the `-path` command to find:

```
find -path "*/project/dir1/dir2" -print
```

Please, notice the `*/` at the beginning. These tells find to print any path that ends with `/project/dir1/dir2` and the name of the first directory has to be `project` otherwise it will find `myproject/dir1/dir2` and such.

Comment: This seems to work.  I tried it earlier and it didn't work but I'm away from my Ubuntu install and was trying to prototype this on an OS X machine.  Works on my *nix machine.  I should have expected that the BSD find wouldn't work the same.

Comment: this worked with MacOS if specifying the root dir to search. i.e. find /home/ -path "*/project/dir1/dir2" -print